# Joint models vs. Cox regression for strictly increasing time-dependent variable

Tags: mixed-model, survival, cox-model, time-varying-covariate

A methodological question without data attached. I've been looking into applying joint models to survival analysis with time-dependent variables. Mainly I've been reading about Dr. Rizopoulos JM package in R, and I have some questions about using the joint model approach. I understand that it is frequently used when you have biomarkers (internal variable with measurement error) such as eGFR, CD4 count, or PSA.

Let's say that you wanted to apply a joint model when you have a time-dependent variable that can only increase in value and only applies to a specific subset of the overall population. Considering you would have to model this using linear mixed models (or similar), would this be possible? Also, as this method is computationally intensive - is it used for very large datasets?

Comment: Does your "time-dependent variable that can only increase in value" have a predictable form (like current age) or is it something that must be measured at each time point?

Comment: What type of analysis are you performing? You mention using linear mixed models which, for a time to event variable with censoring, would be biased. LMMs and Cox models are generally used for very different responses.

Comment: @EdM The variable is an exposure that has to be measured at each time point, but can only increase. It is not age.

Comment: @AdamO I am performing a survival analysis and would normally use Cox regression. However, I've been reading about joint models where you combine mixed linear models (to model a time-dependent variable) and a Cox regression model to get less biased results when dealing with internal variables with measurement error.

Comment: The underlying goal of the analysis was not specified so it’s had to know what approach to take.

Answer (score 1):

Before you proceed, think very carefully about what you are modeling with time-varying covariates. Chapter 10 of [Therneau and Grambsch](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387987842) is one good place to start. The conceptual difficulty is that if you have a new covariate value for an individual at some time, then you know that individual has already survived up to that measurement time. That's not to say you shouldn't do this, just that you need to be careful.

If missing data and measurement errors aren't big problems, then a standard Cox analysis with data coded to handle time-varying covariates might work well enough. Predictor values are often only known to within some error in all types of regression in practice, anyway. Missing data might be handled by multiple imputation. You would have to use your knowledge of the subject matter to decide if those standard approaches are likely to be good enough for your study.

That said, longitudinal modeling of covariates jointly with a survival model can be called for. If your data require such joint modeling, then the [`JM` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=JM) that you cite is one of several implementations.[This page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/561503/28500) has some links to literature and to other packages. The [`frailtypack` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=frailtypack) also might be helpful.

In terms of computational cost, it depends on what you mean by "very large datasets," the available computational resources, the time you're willing to wait, and the modeling approach. [This article](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2021/RJ-2021-028/RJ-2021-028.pdf) shows some plots of computational time versus sample size (up to a few thousand cases) for the `JMcmprsk` package (currently [archived](https://cran.r-project.org/package=JMcmprsk) in CRAN). [This article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11222-020-09927-9), with Dimitris Rizopoulos as senior author, shows how a 2-stage approach can greatly save on computational time over a full multivariate joint model.